# Excel export in xlsx format C#.net, Need a solution to get the export by taking datatable as input

Tags: .net

How can I export a datatable to Excel in xlsx format using c#.net, I tried using XSLT but unable to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

private void Export_with_XSLT_Web(DataSet dsExport, string[] sHeaders, string[] sFileds, ExportFormat FormatType, string FileName)
        {

```
        response.Clear();

        response.Buffer = true;

        if (FormatType == ExportFormat.CSV)
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/csv";
            response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);

        }
        else if (FormatType == ExportFormat.PDF)
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
        }

        // XSLT to use for transforming this dataset.                       
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

        CreateStylesheet(writer, sHeaders, sFileds, FormatType);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(dsExport);
        XslTransform xslTran = new XslTransform();
        xslTran.Load(new XmlTextReader(stream), null, null);

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, sw, null);


        //Writeout the Content              
        response.Write(sw.ToString());
        sw.Close();
        writer.Close();
        stream.Close();
        response.End();

    }
```

private void CreateStylesheet(XmlTextWriter writer, string[] sHeaders, string[] sFileds, ExportFormat FormatType)
        {
            try
            {
                // xsl:stylesheet
                string ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("xsl", "stylesheet", ns);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.0");
                writer.WriteStartElement("xsl:output");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("method", "text");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "4.0");
                writer.WriteEndElement();

```
            // xsl-template
            writer.WriteStartElement("xsl:template");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("match", "/");

            // xsl:value-of for headers
            for (int i = 0; i < sHeaders.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteString("\"");
                writer.WriteStartElement("xsl:value-of");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("select", "'" + sHeaders[i] + "'");
                writer.WriteEndElement(); // xsl:value-of
                writer.WriteString("\"");
                if (i != sFileds.Length - 1) writer.WriteString((FormatType == ExportFormat.CSV) ? "," : "  ");
            }

            // xsl:for-each
            writer.WriteStartElement("xsl:for-each");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("select", "Export/Values");
            writer.WriteString("\r\n");

            // xsl:value-of for data fields
            for (int i = 0; i < sFileds.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteString("\"");
                writer.WriteStartElement("xsl:value-of");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("select", sFileds[i]);
                writer.WriteEndElement(); // xsl:value-of
                writer.WriteString("\"");
                if (i != sFileds.Length - 1) writer.WriteString((FormatType == ExportFormat.CSV) ? "," : "  ");
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement(); // xsl:for-each
            writer.WriteEndElement(); // xsl-template
            writer.WriteEndElement(); // xsl:stylesheet
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }
```